# How to analyze an accidental copy/paste in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, clipboard

While I was trying to copy and paste a command line from a web page, I somehow managed to copy/paste the source code of the entire page, with all the tags and so on (don't ask me how).

This is the page : https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues/29

Of course, the terminal went crazy. As far as I can tell, most of the 'commands' either failed or 'could not be found', but I am not certain.

I was trying to see if any random command had been executed by chance and I realized that I did not know how to properly analyze the situation.

While searching for this issue, I also learned that it can be risky to copy/paste from a website directly into the terminal (that makes sense).

So I have multiple questions regarding this issue and pasting into the terminal:

- Is there way to check if anything was executed? If anything bad happened?
- The 'history' command shows everything, even the commands that failed. Is it possible to see only the last commands that were successful?
- After pasting such a huge 'chunk' of text, the terminal was completely messed up. I could see intermediary failed attempts to execute some commands (bash: syntax error..., command not found) but it looked as if not all the lines were tried. Also, some characters appeared before the username (as if there were no newline after the character). It looked all pretty broken (note that I CTRL-Ced before the end). Is it just a bug with the display or did it have an impact on the execution of the script? In other words, when a very long script is pasted into the terminal, will it be executed completely, orderly and deterministically or does the size mess things up? (or intermediary errors maybe?)
- Right after that, when I looked at the history or used the 'up' arrow, it showed some chunks of 'code' with multiple lines at the same time, but when I closed and reopen my terminal, my history looked 'cleaner', with only one line at a time (kinda matching the source code). How is this possible? Why did the history change?
- Is there a way to prevent this kind of mistake?

(I use the default Ubuntu terminal.)

Sorry, that's a lot of questions...

Comment: See also: [How can I protect myself from this kind of clipboard abuse?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118/78324) at Security SE.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: Well, you should've pasted it again in a file immediately afterwards. As to the history looking cleaner -- try (press "Enter" instead  of each `<cr>`) `echo 'a<cr>echo b<cr>'`: it will be recalled by the `Up` key as a single command (which it is), but it will appear in the history file as if `echo b` was a separate command.